# How to check if a DAG already exists?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to figure out- if it is possible to verify if a DAG already exists in the airflow. For example- if there is an existing DAG named as "dag_execution_1"; I would like to have some sort of procedure to stop uploading a new DAG having the same name.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Airflow>=2.1.0 it's already handled.

If duplicated `dag_id` found it will raise [`AirflowDagDuplicatedIdException`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8b276c6fc191254d96451958609faf81db994b94/airflow/exceptions.py#L132)
Note that the indication is only for the DAG Processor. It's very difficult to handle it accross all Airflow as discussed in https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17891

Answer (score 0):

```
from airflow.models import DagModel

def is_dag_exists(dag_id: str):
    dag = DagModel.get_dagmodel(dag_id)
    if dag is None:
        return False
    return True
```